# how to do something when data from service is ready in angular?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I create service like this :

```
export class MDCurrencyService implements IMDCurrencyService {

        httpService: ng.IHttpService;
        handlerUrl: string;

        constructor($http: ng.IHttpService) {
            this.httpService = $http;
            this.handlerUrl = '/Master/';
        }


        get(): MDCurrency[]{
            var result: MDCurrency[] = [];

            var resp: ng.IPromise<any> = this.httpService.get(this.handlerUrl +'GetAllCurrency')
                .then((response: any): ng.IPromise<any> => this.handlerResponded(response, null));
            resp.then((data) => {
                if (data.is_success) {
                    data.data.forEach(c => {
                        var converted: MDCurrency = <MDCurrency>c;
                        converted.selectedCountry = null;
                        converted.selectedStatus = null;
                        result.push(converted);
                    });
                    return result;
                }
                else return null;

            });
            return result;
        }

        handlerResponded(response: any, params: any): any {
            response.data.requestParams = params;
            return response.data;
        }




    }
```

in my `controller` :

```
$scope.currencies = this.currencies = mdCurrencyService.get();
            if ($scope.currencies.length > 0) {
                console.log('entered'); //never executed
                $scope.currencies.forEach(currency => {
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < this.statuses.length; ii++)
                        if ($scope.statuses[ii].Id == currency.Status)
                            currency.selectedStatus = this.statuses[ii];
                });
            }
```

but after `$scope.currencies` filled from service that `forEach` never executed.
how to execute that code when `$scope.currencies` is filled by data from service?

Comment: Have you implemented `mdCurrencyService` in angular? Does it return the promise?

Comment: Yeah it return,  i want to proccess that data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mdCurrencyService.get()` should be implemented as an asynchronous service returning a promise. It can be utilized this way:

```
mdCurrencyService.get().then(function (currencies) {
    // process result here
    $scope.currencies = currencies;
});
```

Comment: sorry my false, the mdCurrencyService.get() not return promise, am i wrong make it like that?

Comment: sure, mdCurrencyService should be a service making HTTP requests. You may check the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: okay so it my false, i think i can return other than promise, thanks, can you complete your answer, that i have wrong concept? so everyone read this know the true. thanks again